# jquery $.browser removed - code issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, compatibility

I updated my jQuery from 1.3.2 to latest 2.1.0

Now I noticed I have this error on my page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined
```

And here is my code that has this:

```
if(p=='marginRight'&&$.browser.safari)
```

and

```
if($.browser.safari){this.buttons(false,false);
```

I read that from version 1.9 $.browser has been removed, can somebody please help, how can this be fixed? I googled and tried some things but didn't seem to find the right thing..

Thank you

Comment: it just means you have to detect browsers yourself instead of jquery doing it for you

Comment: The modern approach is to look at what features are present, rather than which browser it is. Use something like **modernizr** http://modernizr.com/. This means you need to know what feature the code is wanting to use/avoid (the following lines of code would help).

Comment: Did you look at browser support for the 2.x branch?

Comment: Updating 1.3.2 to 2.x.x is quite a jump.

Answer (score 1):

you can detect browsers via native `navigator` object

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
  // safari
}
```

Comment: That is true, but the OP should try to figure out why they need different behavior in Safari and use feature detection instead, if possible

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just include [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/). This patches in all the functions they removed.

Otherwise, you have to rewrite your code to avoid browser detection. Generally, feature detection is recommended over browser sniffing.

Comment: Just a reminder that that script is just to help you while you migrate. Not so you can keep it in your code, using deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

> The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and
>   is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library
>   such as Modernizr.

Reference: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

Since it has been removed your most simple option here is to use [jquery migrate](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js)